# Resteasy how to update/add query parameter?

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

In older version[**3.0.7**] of resteasy we are able to update the query Parameters

```
requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters()
                        .add("limit", recordLimit);
```

But after updating it with version[**3.5.1**], above code will throw error for `UnmodifiableMultivaluedMap`

Then tried to write this code

```
UriBuilder  uriBuilder = requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUriBuilder();
uriBuilder.queryParam("limit", recordLimit);
```

as well as below code

```
UriBuilder  uriBuilder = requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUriBuilder();
uriBuilder.matrixParam("limit", recordLimit);
```

Can someone please explain what will be the right way to update the query parameters ?

**Edit 1**: Even this wont work

```
UriBuilder  uriBuilder = requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUriBuilder();
uriBuilder.replaceQueryParam( "limit", recordLimit);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to update the query parameters?

Comment: Actually in our case `limit` will tell how many record user want to fetch at a time if user wont give this value in url then we will pick this value from the properties file and fetch that many record in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i found the solution,in older version we are doing something like that to add query param on fly

```
requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters()
                        .add("limit", recordLimit);
```

but in 3.5.1 version its a MultiMap so above scenario wont allow so here is the new way to achieve this

```
UriBuilder  uriBuilder = requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUriBuilder() ;
uriBuilder.queryParam("limit", recordLimit);
requestContext.setRequestUri(uriBuilder.build());
```